# SQL invalid conversion return null instead of throwing error

Tags: t-sql, invalid-characters

I have a table with a varchar column, and I want to find values that match a certain number.  So lets say that column contains the following entries (except with millions of rows in real life):

```
123456789012
2345678
3456
23 45
713?2
00123456789012
```

So I decide I want all the rows which are numerically 123456789012 write a statement that looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CAST(MyColumn as bigint) = 123456789012
```

It should return the first and last row, but instead the whole query blows up because it can't convert the "23 45" and "713?2" to bigint.

Is there another way to do the conversion that will return NULL for values that can't convert?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server does NOT guarantee boolean operator short-circuit, see [On SQL Server boolean operator short-circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/). So all solution using `ISNUMERIC(...) AND CAST(...)` are fundamentally flawed (they may work, but hey can arbitrarily fail later dependiong on the generated plan). A better solution is using CASE, as Thomas suggests: `CASE ISNUMERIC(...) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(...) ELSE NULL END`. But, as gbn pointed out, `ISNUMERIC` is notoriously finicky in identifying what 'numeric' means and many cases where one would expect it to return 0 it returns 1. So mixing the CASE with the LIKE:

```
CASE WHEN MyRow NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN CAST(MyRow as bigint) ELSE NULL END
```

But the real problem is that if you have millions of rows and you have to search them like this, you'll always end up scanning end-to-end since the expression is not SARG-able (no matter how we rewrite it). The real issue here is data purity, and should be addressed at the appropriate level, where the data is populated. Another thing to consider is if is possible to create a persisted computed column with this expression and create a filtered index on it which eliminates NULL (ie. non-numeric). That would speed up things a little.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to avoid creating a derived column of some sort (which would introduce a lot of other complications), but I guess I'll just have to bite the bullet and do that.  Is it better to use a trigger to keep it up to date, or is there some better way?

Comment: Indexed view is the other way: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 you can use the 2 new methods:

- [TRY_CAST()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [TRY_CONVERT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)

Both methods are equivalent. They return a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null. The only difference is that CONVERT is SQL Server specific, CAST is ANSI. using CAST will make your code more portable (although not sure if any other database provider implements TRY_CAST)

Answer (score 4):

ISNUMERIC will accept empty string and values like 1.23 or 5E-04 so could be unreliable.

And you don't know what order things will be evaluated in so it could still fail (SQL is declarative, not procedural, so the WHERE clause probably won't be evaluated left to right)

So:

- you want to accept value that consist *only* of the characters 0-9
- you need to materialise the "number" filter so it's applied before CAST

Something like:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
   (
   SELECT TOP 2000000000 *
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE MyColumn NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'  --double negative rejects anything except 0-9
   ORDER BY MyColumn 
   ) foo
WHERE 
    CAST(MyColumn as bigint) = 123456789012 --applied after number check
```

Edit: quick example that fails.

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (bigintstring varchar(100))
INSERT #foo (bigintstring )VALUES ('1.23')
INSERT #foo (bigintstring )VALUES ('1 23')
INSERT #foo (bigintstring )VALUES ('123')

SELECT * FROM #foo
WHERE
   ISNUMERIC(bigintstring) = 1 
   AND 
   CAST(bigintstring AS bigint) = 123
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that ISNUMERIC is not reliable for this (since other people are claiming it as sufficient).  Unfortunately, I don't think the "NOT LIKE" syntax is going to play too well with indexes.  Remember that this table has many millions of rows.

Comment: @Bryce Wagner: indexes will not be used with a function on the column. NOT LIKE will be no different to ISNUMERIC or CAST in this case. Edit: As Remus answered...

Comment: Also, it would greatly simplify your solution to use CASE WHEN MyColumn NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN NULL ELSE CAST(MyColumn AS bigint) instead of doing it in a subselect (but again, I don't think this will play well with the index).

Comment: @Bryce Wagner: it makes *no difference* whether you use CASE or materialise. CASE also invalidates indexes too. As Remus mentioned there is no "good" solution to your problem. Feel free to run the query with float, CASE, materialised table etc and report back...

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that trying to patch a subselect like that into an already complex query would be a major pain, but using CASE would make the query a lot simpler to work with.  Not that it would affect optimization in any way.

Comment: FYI, the value "+" returns true for ISNUMERIC.  And will cast to a bigint, but WON'T cast to a decimal.  Crazy.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable 
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(MyRow) = 1
        AND CAST(MyRow as float) = 123456789012
```

Comment: @gbn: Modified my CAST to float instead of bigint. I believe that would be sufficient to address your concerns? Values like 1.23 and 5E-04 will pass the ISNUMERIC test and will convert, but they'll not match the value being sought.

Comment: Yes, agree it's more tolerant. It still depends on fixed order of WHERE condition valuation:-) Need a CASE now in the WHERE clause...

Comment: FYI, ISNUMERIC("+") returns 1, but you get the error "Error converting data type varchar to float." when casting as a float.

Answer (score 0):

The ISNUMERIC() function should give you what you need.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE ISNUMERIC(MyRow) = 1
AND CAST(MyRow as bigint) = 123456789012
```

And to add a case statement like Thomas suggested:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE CASE(ISNUMERIC(MyRow)
        WHEN 1 THEN CAST(MyRow as bigint)
        ELSE NULL
      END = 123456789012
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (ISNUMERIC(MyColumn) = 1) AND (CAST(MyColumn as bigint) = 123456789012)
```

Additionally you can use a CASE statement in order to get null values.

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN (ISNUMERIC(MyColumn) = 1) THEN CAST(MyColumn as bigint)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS 'MyColumnAsBigInt'
FROM tableName
```

If you require additional filtering, for numerics which are not valid to be cast to bigint, you can use the following instead of ISNUMERIC:

PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',MyColumn)) = 0

If you need decimal values instead of integers, cast to float instead and change the regex to '%[^0-9.]%'

Comment: Sorry, you're correct about MyRow, that's actually a column, not a row :-)  Fixed now.

Comment: Please see my answer: won't work for values like 1.23 or 5E-04